# How to set a max width for a material button in flutter on wider screens?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, button

My Material buttons are too big and I need a way to give them a max width. I tried Contarinedbox and it does not work here is my code:

```
Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 100.0, right: 100.0),
            child: MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const RiderSignup()),
                );
              },
              color: Colors.teal,
              child: const Text("Rider Sign-up",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            ),
          ),
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried simple SizedBox instead, by wrapping the MaterialButton with it?

Comment: SizedBox, or maybe IntrinsicWidth?

Answer (score 1):

As your code is not completely reproducible. I am assuming you are using `Column` widget to organiz your screen. Following will be the correct way to do it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
      Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children :[
          UnconstrainedBox(
          child:Container(
            width:200,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 100.0, right: 100.0),
            child: MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Scaffold()),
                );
              },
              color: Colors.teal,
              child: const Text("Rider Sign-up",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            ),
          ),),

        ]
      )
      ;
  }
}
```

I have added an extra widget `UnConstrainedBox` that is parent of your `Container` widget this will make the Container to be free from any 'Constraineds' Column widget adds to its children.